# setStatus(1) for Store ID 1 but use setStatus(2) as default

Tags: magento-1.9

We have an importer were the products should be disabled by default, but enabled for just one specific store ID.

I use the following:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);          $product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE);             $product->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
$product->setWebsiteIds(array($this->magentoWebsiteId));
$product->setStoreId($this->getMagentoStoreId());
$product->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
```

However, the products are are not disabled in "default". How can I disable the product by default for every store, but not for one specific?

Comment: Need to pass specific store id in  $product->setStoreId(STORE-ID);

Comment: This gets done on line 4, theres a function to receive the correct store (i.e. 2 or 1)

Comment: Had you tried with pass static value like "1" or "2"?

Comment: Yes, doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code at end of your code with the store code for make product disable for that store:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->updateProductStatus($product_id, $storeId, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
```

Also dont forgot to do indexing after it.

For example if there are store : 1,2,3. and you want to enable product in 1 store and disable in 2 and 3 store

then your code should be like below:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->updateProductStatus($product_id, 1, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->updateProductStatus($product_id, 2, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->updateProductStatus($product_id, 3, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
```

Comment: This is just partially what I need. How can I just enable it for one store, but not for any store else?

Comment: @Max , check updated answer.